# Android addTab favSpec

Tags: android, tabs, illegalargumentexception

Good morning!

I've been getting

> "TabView java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to
>   create the tab content"

while creating TabSpec favSpec, this is the chunk of code where the fault line appears:

```
mTabHost.addTab(registerSpec);
mTabHost.addTab(weatherSpec);
mTabHost.addTab(commentSpec);
mTabHost.addTab(contactSpec);
mTabHost.addTab(localizationSpec);
mTabHost.addTab(mapSpec);
mTabHost.addTab(termsSpec);
mTabHost.addTab(favSpec); // This is the fault line
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The content of favSpec was not being created due to the lexical error, thus tab of favSpec was empty :) As soon as I gave it content, everything was OK.